# How to get Conga trigger to create Salesforce case

Tags: apex, case, email2case, triggered-send, conga

I have a scenario where Conga Trigger is being used to send communication through a flow that is not attached to a Case in Salesforce. When a customer replies to the conga automated email, it keeps creating a new case each time in Salesforce. Need the solution to generate a case at time of comms being sent, so duplicate cases are no longer being created - responses rollup to Case.

a) is there a way I can use Conga trigger in flow to create a case upon send & link it to a particular object I am sending from? So each reply, rolls back up to the case OR

b) is this something that needs an apex trigger?

c) or is there a much simplier way & I'm getting ahead of myself?

Comment: You will have to check with Conga support.